# Can GitLab run a CI pipeline on each new commit of a pushed branch?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Suppose I have a local feature branch with 10 commits (in a linear fashion). I also have a GitLab CI pipeline checking various things about my code (spell check, formatting, static analysis).

My goal is to not only check that the pipeline passes for the last commit (the tip of the branch), but also for each and every commits in the branch after the one I branched off of. So, in my case, I would like to have 10 pipelines running on these 10 commits that constitute my feature branch.

Is it possible to do that in GitLab? when we push a branch, in a merge request or in any other way?

Comment: By default, it will run a pipeline on each push, so you could push each one separately. If you want to check all new commits on a single push, that would likely require more complex scripting.

Comment: @Arty-chan Yes, I would like to check all new commits on a single push. What kind a script would I need? Do you know any documentation that would help me achieve this goal?

Comment: Basically, you'd likely want the existing job to compare the latest commit hash and the hash of the previous pipeline and trigger new pipelines for each commit? I'm not 100% certain that's possible. Not aware of anything, but I recommend updating your question to clarify to problem, and what you've tried.